# Angular 4 with Angularfire2 and Firebase 4 Syntax Migration issues

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Basically I'm trying to convert my angular 2.3.1 and firebase 2.x.x project to the latest version, I'm having some issues with getting the syntax and imports correct. I've been using https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/956 but am confused as they import { AngularFireAuthModule } but then reference it as afAuth: AngularfireAuth. I have managed to fix some errors elsewhere, but am having difficulty getting the authentication area working. Even reference to a good resource would of help, the videos on youtube seem to be for older versions and what I used originally.

Also any advice on improving app.modules.ts / my code is appreciated.

```
ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (2,10): Module '"C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFire'.

ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (21,17): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.

ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (50,10): Property 'af' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.

ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (51,17): Cannot find name 'AuthProviders'.

ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (52,15): Cannot find name 'AuthMethods'.

ERROR in C:/Users/User/Desktop/Projects/angular2/changingLives/src/app/components/account/login/login.component.ts (66,12): Property 'af' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.
```

Code for this module.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  state: string = '';
  error: any;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
              private router: Router) {

    this.afAuth.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginFb() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
  }

  /*loginFb() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then(
      (success) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }).catch(
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    )
  }*/

  loginGoogle() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then(
      (success) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }).catch(
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    )
  }

  onSubmit(formData) {
    if (formData.valid) {
      console.log(formData.value);
      this.af.auth.login({
        email: formData.value.email,
        password: formData.value.password
      }).then(
        (success) => {
          console.log(success);
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
        }).catch(
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.error = err;
        }
      )
    }
  }


  //login() {
  //  this.af.auth.login();
  //}

}
```

app.modules.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; // added to provide routes
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2'; // Adding angularfire
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

// services
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service'; // must be added to the providers below.

// component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/account/login/login.component';
import { ListingsComponent } from './components/demo/listings/listings.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/content/navbar/navbar.component';
import { ListingComponent } from './components/demo/listing/listing.component';
import { AddListingComponent } from './components/demo/add-listing/add-listing.component';
import { EditListingComponent } from './components/demo/edit-listing/edit-listing.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/account/signup/signup.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/content/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginEmailComponent } from './components/account/login-email/login-email.component';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'listings', component:ListingsComponent},
  {path: 'listing/:id', component: ListingComponent}, //:id to pass id
  {path: 'add-listing', component:AddListingComponent},
  {path: 'edit-listing/:id', component:EditListingComponent}, //:id to pass id
  {path: 'signup', component:SignupComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'login-email', component:LoginEmailComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ListingsComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ListingComponent,
    AddListingComponent,
    EditListingComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginEmailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FlashMessagesModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), //appRoutes is array of stored routes.
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule

  ],
  providers: [FirebaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you. Use firebase SDK for authentication instead of AngularFire. 
In your LoginComponent import firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

And it the constructor you can do something like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
      (user) => {
        if (!user) {
          console.log("NOT LOGGED IN");
        } else {
          console.log("Logged In as: ", user);
        }
      });
```

For Facebook authentication is very similar, see the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login